# Method not found: 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1<..> ..Entities.get_tb_BrandManufacturer()'

Tags: entity-framework-6

added new tables to DB, run EF update (DB first), no errors, builds fine. When running it throws

System.MissingMethodException occurred
  HResult=0x80131513
  Message=Method not found: 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1 DAL.EF.LPEntities.get_tb_BrandManufacturer()'.
  Source=LP.Framework

on new tables added. Only happens at runtime.
Thanks
Pavel

Comment: I meant only affect queries with the new tables..

Comment: update: after closing, cleaning up and rebuilding solution it throws new error "The entity type tb_BrandManufacturer is not part of the model for the current context"

Answer (score 0):

After closing, re-opening with all projects loaded (it's a fairly large solution so some projects unloaded when working on feature), removing and adding tables to EF designer again, rebuilding it started to work.